# TSQL Having clause not performing as expected with condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, having

```
DECLARE @ComparisonMonth DATE
SET @ComparsionMonth '09-01-2018'

SELECT 
    Date, Sales, CustomerID 
FROM
    Database1 t1
WHERE
    Date >= CASE 
               WHEN (SELECT MAX(Date) 
                     FROM Database1 t2 
                     INNER JOIN ON t1.PlayerID = t2.PlayerID) >= DATEADD(month, -4, @ComparisonMonth) 
                    AND (SELECT MAX(Date) 
                         FROM Database1 t2 
                         INNER JOIN ON t1.PlayerID = t2.PlayerID) < DATEADD(month, -1, @ComparsionMonth) 
                  THEN DATEADD(month, -4, @ComparisonMonth)
               WHEN (SELECT MAX(Date) 
                     FROM Database1 t2 
                     INNER JOIN ON t1.PlayerID = t2.PlayerID) >= DATEADD(month, -7, @ComparisonMonth) 
                    AND (SELECT MAX(Date) 
                         FROM Database1 t2 
                         INNER JOIN ON t1.PlayerID = t2.PlayerID) < DATEADD(month, -4, @ComparsionMonth) 
                  THEN DATEADD(month, -7, @ComparisonMonth)
            END
        AND Date < CASE 
                      WHEN (Select MAX(Date) from Database1 t2 INNER JOIN on t1.PlayerID=t2.PlayerID) >= DATEADD(month, -4, @ComparisonMonth) 
                           AND (Select MAX(Date) from Database1 t2 INNER JOIN on t1.PlayerID=t2.PlayerID) < DATEADD(month, -1, @ComparsionMonth)          
                         THEN DATEADD(month, -1, @ComparisonMonth)
                      WHEN (Select MAX(Date) from Database1 t2 INNER JOIN on t1.PlayerID=t2.PlayerID) >= DATEADD(month, -7, @ComparisonMonth) 
                           AND (Select MAX(Date) from Database1 t2 INNER JOIN on t1.PlayerID=t2.PlayerID) < DATEADD(month, -4, @ComparsionMonth) 
                         THEN DATEADD(month, -4, @ComparisonMonth)
                    END

    GROUP BY
        CustomerID, Date
```

Basically, I want to show only the values for a specific period depending on when the customer last purchased an item. For example, if a customer last purchased an item within the last 3 months I want to take all of their transactions from the last 3 months. Instead, i am getting the transactions from 6 months for the customer that last came in 3 months ago.

Thanks so much for the help and please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: But if the customer last purchased an item 3 months ago, why do you need to sum up the sales of the last 3 months for this specific customer when you know that only the month he last purchased contains sales? Or am i getting it wrong?

Comment: `HAVING` should be applied only to **aggregates** of columns, e.g. to `SUM(...)`, or `COUNT(.....)`. When checking just a regular column directly, without aggregation, use the `WHERE` clause instead

Comment: @randomDude1001 Basically, I want to take a 3 month period of sales for a specific customer for marketing offers and based on when they last came in it determines which months I use for this 3 month window. The month he last purchased contains sales but I don't want the months sales prior to the 3 month period to show up on my query result. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @marc_s But, I am using aggregates I need to use the max function in order to determine the last date a customer came in and I can't do this within a where clause.

Comment: No you're **NOT** using an aggregate in the condition - you check for `Date` column directly ...

Comment: `GROUP BY ... Date` and `MAX(Date)` ?

Comment: `last purchased`, `last came` - I see only one `date` column. So which date is that?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Sorry for the confusion, came was wrong word. I am looking for when a customer last purchased and the combination of date,sales,customer id gives that. I tried to select MAX(GamingDate) and group by date but I just get the max for each transaction, rather than for the customer overall.

Comment: @marc_s I see what you mean now, now I got to figure out how to incorporate the max date in a where clause

Comment: Perhaps you could use the quarter of the last purchase as your time period? If so, you just need `SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER, date)` and limit your query to the quarter when the last purchase happend per customer.

Comment: @randomDude1001 Unfortunately, that will not work, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I have found a way to get my expected result but it takes extremely long to run, any suggestions. (edited above). Used a subquery in a where clause to get max date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to stop trying to achieve everything at once. Split your query to:

1 Find customers you need. Very simple query with precise filter condition:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (CustomerID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, LastPurchase DATE, FirstTran DATE)

INSERT INTO @Customers(CustomerID, LastPurchase, FirstTran)
SELECT 
    CustomerID, MAX(Date), DATEADD(MM, -3, MAX(Date))
FROM Database1 d
WHERE d.date >= @ReportDate
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

2 Fetch their transactions. Now you have good filter (join predicate) again - CustomerID. Help server with filtering big table - find absolutely minimal date from collected data.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE

SELECT @MinDate = MIN(FirstTran)
FROM @Customers

SELECT d.*
FROM Database1 d
INNER JOIN @Customers c
on c.CustomerID = d.CustomerID
WHERE d.Date >= c.FirstTran
  AND d.Date >= @MinDate
```

Test your solution and if you will ever come up with some tiny single-step solution - refactor this code as you wish.

Comment: Thank you, this brought me down the right path, I should have split up the operation to begin with.